# How upload Image from ViewModel to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am sending you a link to the previous post here.

[How to insert data from ViewModel to Database with using dropdown list in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738852/how-to-insert-data-from-viewmodel-to-database-with-using-dropdown-list-in-view)

The problem now concerns the transfer of image parameters.

I would like to upload a photo to the main Model with ViewModel to send the data to the database.
This is not a mass transfer of files, only individual files to the table.

Both model parameters are set to:

```cs
[Display(Name ="Photo")]
public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
```

I tried to set models according to Microsoft ASP.NET Core v 2.2 documentation

My attempt at the Controller [HttpPost]:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(... , byte[] Photo, IFormFile Image)
        {
            ObjectABC abc = new ObjectABC ();
            ObjectViewModel model = new ObjectViewModel ();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (... && Image != null)
                {
                    ...
                    abc.Photo = Photo;

                    _context.Add(abc);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }  
         
            Photo = null;

             using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
             {
                 Image.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                 Photo = memoryStream.ToArray();
             }

            ...
            model.Photo = Photo;

            return View(model);
        }
```

for the [HttpGet] controller I did not set anything, I left it as suggested in the previous solution.
part View:

```
...
            <div class="form-gr">
                <input type="file" asp-for="Photo" class="form-control" />
                <label asp-for="Photo" class="control-label">Browse...</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Photo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
...
```

Everything looks OK, but the program says:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> ...
>
> +
>
> ```
>              Image.CopyTo(memoryStream);
> ```

**Where is it incorrectly set up, what is the reason I have this result? Any ideas ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I gave up VARBINARY (MAX) and changed the database to string as storing file names. I know this is less secure. But it's good that it works. My solution:

In the models I changed from byte [] to string

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(... IFormFile Photo)
        {
            ObjectViewModel model = new ObjectViewModel ();


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string uidFileName = null;

                if (... && Photo != null)
                {
                    string uploadFolder = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images");
                    uidFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(Photo.FileName);
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, uidFileName);
                    Photo.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));

                    ObjectABC abc = new ObjectABC()
                    {
                        ...
                        Photo = uidFileName
                    };

                    _context.Add(abc);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }           

           ...

            ...
            model.Photo = Photo;

            return View(model);
        }
```